# Simple code in C++ compiling but not executing in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile and execute a simple code in C++ on a linux machine. But the program gets stuck in the middle of the code. I can't find the reason.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int n;
int product =1;
int counter =0;
int p;
int main()
{
    //return 1;
    cout << "How many numbers?" << endl;
    cin >> n ;
    cout << "Input the numbers " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                cin >> p;
                product = product*p;
                int p = 1;
        }
        cout << "Now our number to be factorised is " << product << endl;
        cin >> p;
        for(int i=1;i=product;i++)
        {
         if(product%i==0)
         counter++;
        }
         cout << "the number of factors is " << counter << endl;
          return 0;
}
```

The code gets stuck at "Now our number to be factorised is " product. It calculates the product but doesn't progress any further

Comment: It calculates the *product* but doesn't go any further

Comment: You should have used a debugger to step through the code and see where it gets stuck. You could step through the `for` loop and see why the condition is always true.

Comment: use 'for(int i=1;i==product;i++)' Instead of 'for(int i=1;i=product;i++)' in Second loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because **infinite loop**, in second for loop you have misspelled `==` :

```
for(int i=1;i=product;i++)
             ^
               should be ==
```

**Side note**: To minimize such kind of bugs in you code I would suggest you to keep space in expression e.g. an expression `i=product`  should be written as `i = product`, so that its readable. similarly you should add space after `;` and `,`.

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised the compiler didn't warn about this. OP, try building with `-Wall`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had corrected this mistake previously but when I pasted the entire code again where I was compiling it, I forgot to make the change again. Silly mistake :D :D :P
Thanks.

Comment: @PiyushShandilya no problem! I would like to add some words wait!

Comment: It's _legal_, but it's also a common typo. `g++ -Wall` gives _suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value_, which is at least a clue.

Comment: @PiyushShandilya I added a side note please read. it make your code bit readable so that `i=1` become bit visualize.

Comment: @PiyushShandilya there's a couple of other issues with your code - not bugs per se, but you should fix them. One is that you never check for input failure from your `cin` statements - that's a bad habit to get into; another is that `int p = 1;` inside the `for` loop. Why is that there and do you think that line of code does?

Comment: @Useless thanks!! it helpful I didn't try, does `gcc` give warning **?**

Comment: Yes, I pasted the option and the warning above.

Comment: @NikBougalis So that the previous value doesn't get multiplied again.

Comment: @PiyushShandilya think again... `int p = 1` declares a different variable named `p` (which hides or *"shadows"* the other `p`). `p = 1` is probably want you meant to do, but even that is unnecessary in the code you show, since you read `p` in the loop before using it.

Comment: @PiyushShandilya [you may like to accept an answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes you have a typo on this line:

```
for(int i=1;i=product;i++)
             ^
```

you are using assignment(`=`) instead of logical equals(`==`). So this is effectively an infinite loop since the result of this expression is `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had corrected this mistake previously but when I pasted the entire code again where I was compiling it, I forgot to make the change again. Silly mistake :D :D :P
Thanks.